# Guessing game using random number. How to get new number without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript

Im relativly new to js so im making a gueessing game from 1 to 100 using Math.random to get my random number. I have a play again button that clears all previous guesses from a previous round but when you click it the random number does not change so the next rounds number is the same

I tried stating random again in the play again function but it did not work and I also tried putting the variable in the function but then it changed upon every guess the user inputed

```
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
console.log(random)
const guess = document.querySelector('.guess')
const button = document.querySelector('.submit')
const myForm = document.querySelector('.myForm')
let numguesses = 0

myForm.addEventListener('submit', click)

function click(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     const ul = document.querySelector('.guesses')
     
     if(guess.value > 100 || guess.value < 0 || isNaN(guess.value)) {
        alert("please a enter number between  0 to 100")
      } else {
        numguesses++;
     if(random != guess.value) {
         if(guess.value > random) {
             const eachguess = document.createElement('li')
             eachguess.innerText= `${guess.value} was too High`
             eachguess.classList.add('wrong')
             ul.append(eachguess)
             guess.value = '';
         } else {
             const eachguess = document.createElement('li')
             eachguess.innerText = `${guess.value} was too Low`
             eachguess.classList.add('low')
             ul.append(eachguess)
             guess.value = '';
         } 
     } else {
        const eachguess = document.createElement('li')
        eachguess.innerText = `Well done you gueesed Correctly the number was ${random} it took ${numguesses} guesses`
        eachguess.classList.add('correct')
        ul.append(eachguess)  
        guess.value = '' 
        return 
     }  
  }   
}

const PlayAgain = document.querySelector('#playAgain')

PlayAgain.addEventListener('click', Play)

function Play() {
    const ul = document.querySelector('.guesses')
    while (ul.firstChild) {
        ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild)
        numguesses = 0
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a new value within the Play function:

```
let random;

// ...

function Play() {
    const ul = document.querySelector('.guesses')
    while (ul.firstChild) {
        ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild)           
    }
    numguesses = 0
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) // <------
    console.log(random)
}
```

You must not add the `let` keyword here as that would declare the `random` variable **locally** within the Play function - but in your case you want to **re-assign the existing variable** from the outer scope).